# JASidePanel > CenterPanel hidden rightBarButtonItems

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, jasidepanels

I'm using [JASSidePanels](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels) to implement the left menu effect (like Facebook iOS app).

My CenterPanel has 3 `rightBarButtonItems`.

When the LeftPanel is showed, the CenterPanel is moved to right and the 3 rightBarButtonItems of CenterPanel are hidden.

How can I keep the `rightBarButtonItems` of CenterPanel always visible, even when LeftPanel is shown? (like the Dropbox iOS App)?